# ImageFile doesn`t work, don`t know what the problem is in

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload a picture, but it doesn't work. No mistake returns, like if it is uploaded and self.validated_data['picture'] or serializer.self.validated_data['picture'] prints are not empty, but 'picture' in JSON stays null - it mustn`t. Nothing loads to media files, nothing is in DB

Views

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def api_pictures(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    pictures = Picture.objects.all()
    serializer = PictureSerializer(pictures, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = PictureSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        print(serializer.validated_data['picture'])
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#Models

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    pic_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    picture =models.ImageField(upload_to='media_site/',blank=True,
height_field='height', width_field='width')
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

#Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include(router.urls)),
    path("api/images/", api_pictures),
    path("api/images/<int:pk>", detail_pictures),
]
```

#Serializers.py

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    @staticmethod
    def name_parser(object_name):
        parser = re.search(r'[^/]*$', str(object_name))
        return parser[0]
def save(self):
    if 'picture' not in self.validated_data.keys():
        url = self.validated_data['url']
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(url=url)
        img = BytesIO(result.read())
        converted_img = InMemoryUploadedFile(img, None, self.name_parser(url),
                                             'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(img), None)
        print(converted_img)
        self.validated_data.update({'picture': converted_img})
    else:
        self.validated_data.update({'picture': self.validated_data['picture']})
    if 'pic_name' not in self.validated_data.keys():
        name = self.name_parser(self.validated_data['picture'])
        self.validated_data.update({'pic_name': name})

class Meta:
    model = Picture
    fields = ('id', 'pic_name', 'picture', 'url', 'width', 'height')
```

result

[image: postman screen]

But 'picture' mustn`t be null :((((

When i upload it self.validated_data['picture'] is not empty. Django returns no mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I should have initialized `super.save()` after function overriding in `PictureSerializer` class.